# While loop stops after first iteration

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop, warnings

I'm running a script which constructs and sends emails to clients if current date matches date from database.

My problem is that the while loop stops after the first iteration and outputs the following Warning:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::fetch() [mysqli-stmt.fetch]: Couldn't fetch
>   mysqli_stmt in *filepath* on line 17

The first iteration works flawlessly and sends the email correctly. I'm pasting the whole while loop below as I'm not sure where the error occurs..

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$sent = '0';

    // fech all info where firstdate is today
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ex_id,ex_type,ex_comp,ex_firstname,ex_lastname,ex_email,ex_template,ex_attachments FROM execute WHERE ex_firstDate = ? AND ex_sent = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('si',$today,$sent);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($first_id,$first_type,$first_comp,$first_firstname,$first_lastname,$first_email,$first_template,$first_attachments);

            // loop through
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            if (empty($first_id) || $first_id == 0) {
                $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." - N/A - NO RECIPIENT FIRST DATE :\r\n";
                fwrite($handle, $current);
                continue;
            }

            if ($first_type == 1) {
                $stmt_b = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT unsub_email FROM unsubscribe WHERE unsub_program = 1");
                $stmt_b->execute();
                $stmt_b->store_result();
                $stmt_b->bind_result($unsub_email);

                while ($row_unsub = $stmt_b->fetch()) {
                    if ($first_email == $unsub_email) {
                        $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." - Opt-out - PROGRAM #".$first_id." :\r\n";
                        fwrite($handle, $current);
                        continue 2;
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($first_type == 2) {
                $stmt_b = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT unsub_email FROM unsubscribe WHERE unsub_cat = 1");
                $stmt_b->execute();
                $stmt_b->store_result();
                $stmt_b->bind_result($unsub_email);

                while ($row_unsub = $stmt_b->fetch()) {
                    if ($first_email == $unsub_email) {
                        $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." - Opt-out - CATEGORY #".$first_id." :\r\n";
                        fwrite($handle, $current);
                        continue 2;
                    }
                }
            }

            $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." - Success - GET RECIPIENT FIRST #".$first_id." :\r\n";
            fwrite($handle, $current);

            $id = $first_template;
            $preview = false;

            $builder_type = $first_type;

            if (empty($first_comp)) {
                $builder_comp = '';
            }  else {
                $builder_comp = $first_comp;
            }

            if (empty($first_firstname)) {
                $builder_firstname = '';
            } else {
                $builder_firstname = $first_firstname;
            }

            if (empty($first_lastname)) {
                $builder_lastname = '';
            } else {
                $builder_lastname = $first_lastname;
            }

            if (empty($first_email)) {
                $builder_email = '';
            } else {
                $builder_email = $first_email;
            }

                    //Create a new PHPMailer instance
            require_once(__DIR__.'/../email/email_builder.php');

            $mail = new PHPMailer;

            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
            $mail->Encoding = '8bit';

            // To load the Swedish version
            $mail->setLanguage('se', __DIR__.'../email/PHPMailer-master/language/');

            //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
            $mail->isSMTP();

            //Enable SMTP debugging
            // 0 = off (for production use)
            // 1 = client messages
            // 2 = client and server messages
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

            //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
            $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

            //Set the hostname of the mail server
            $mail->Host = 'HOST';

            //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
            $mail->Port = 587;

            //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

            //Whether to use SMTP authentication
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

            //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
            $mail->Username = "USERNAME";

            //Password to use for SMTP authentication
            $mail->Password = "PASSWORD";

            //Set who the message is to be sent from
            $mail->setFrom($db_fromEmail, $db_fromName);

            //Set an alternative reply-to address
            $mail->addReplyTo($db_respondEmail, $db_respondName);

            //Set the subject line
            $mail->Subject = $db_subject;

            //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
            //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
            $mail->msgHTML($html);

            // create alt plain text body
            $plain_text = Html2Text\Html2Text::convert($db_content.$plain_text_footer);

            $mail->AltBody = $plain_text;

            $mail->addAddress($first_email);

            if (!empty($first_attachments) && $first_attachments != 0) {
                $array_attach = explode(',', $first_attachments);
                $array_attach = array_map('trim', $array_attach);

                foreach ($array_attach as $key) {
                    if ($stmt_a = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT attach_name,attach_path,attach_type FROM attachments WHERE attach_id = ?")) {
                        $stmt_a->bind_param('i',$key);
                        if ($stmt_a->execute()) {
                            $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." - Success - ADD ATTACHMENT FIRST #".$first_id."\r\n";
                            fwrite($handle, $current);

                            $stmt_a->store_result();
                            $stmt_a->bind_result($attach_name,$attach_path,$attach_type);
                            $stmt_a->fetch();

                            $full_path = __DIR__.'/../'.$attach_path;
                            $full_name = $attach_name.$attach_type;

                            $mail->addAttachment($full_path,$full_name);
                        } else {
                            $error = $stmt_a->error;
                            $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." - Error - ADD ATTACHMENT FIRST #".$first_id." : ".$error."\r\n";
                            fwrite($handle, $current);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $error = $stmt_a->error;
                        $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." - Error - ADD ATTACHMENT FIRST #".$first_id." : ".$error."\r\n";
                        fwrite($handle, $current);
                    }
                }
            }

            if($mail->send()) {
                $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." - Success - SENT RECIPIENT FIRST ".$first_id."\r\n";
                fwrite($handle, $current);

                $sent_db = '1';

                if ($stmt_s = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE execute SET ex_sent = ? WHERE ex_id = ?")) {
                    $stmt_s->bind_param('ii',$sent_db,$first_id);
                    if ($stmt_s->execute()) {
                        $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." - Success - SENT UPDATE DB FIRST #".$first_id."\r\n";
                        fwrite($handle, $current);
                    } else {
                        $error = $stmt_s->error;
                        $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." - Error - SENT UPDATE DB FIRST #".$first_id." : ".$error."\r\n";
                        fwrite($handle, $current);
                    }
                } else {
                    $error = $stmt_s->error;
                    $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." - Error - SENT UPDATE DB FIRST #".$first_id." : ".$error."\r\n";
                    fwrite($handle, $current);
                }
            } else {
                $error = $mail->ErrorInfo;
                $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." - Error - SENT RECIPIENT FIRST #".$first_id." : ".$error."\r\n";
                fwrite($handle, $current);
            }

            $mail->clearAddresses();
            $mail->clearAttachments();
        }
    } else {
        $error = $stmt->error;
        $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." - Error - GET TEMPLATE FIRST : ".$error."\r\n";
        fwrite($handle, $current);
    }
} else {
    $error = $stmt->error;
    $current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." - N/A - GET TEMPLATE FIRST : ".$error."\r\n";
    fwrite($handle, $current);
}

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Hi i suspect you  are killing the dataset somewhere. just use  mysqli_num_rows to make sure that you have more than 1 row

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, the email builder file included in the code contained another *$stmt* variable with the same variable name as the while loops was based on, forcing it to crash...